# Why does my Eee PC try to mount the extended /swap partition?

Tags: swap, automount, pcmanfm

In PCManFM on the left side there is a volume called "1,0 KB Volume". When I click on it, it shows an error message that it can't mount /dev/sda2, but /dev/sda2 is extended partition with the swap partition /dev/sda5. Why does PCManFM try to mount it?

[image]